# Dictionary unique values in comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a little task which I solved.

Task: find all PAIRS in a sequence which sum up to a certain number.

For example (1,2,3,4) and target 3 yields one pair (1,2).

I came up with a solution:

```
def pair(lst, find):
res = []
for i in lst:
    if (find - i) in lst:
        res.append([(find - i),i])
        
return {x:y for x,y in res}
```

I'm a bit surprised to see the dictionary comprehension filter all duplicate solutions.

Which actually forms my question: how and why a dictionary comprehension removes duplicates?

Comment: Keys in a dictionary are supposed to be unique.

Comment: `hash` along with moduleo is used to calculate the index where keys are stored. So if both the hash are same, they will get overwritten.

Comment: I like to think of a dictionary comprehension as creating a `dict` and then inserting each `x:y` sequentially. Obviously any `x` which has a value that is already present as a key is never duplicated. It just overwrites the existing `y` value. It would be surprising to print out a `dict` and find duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2):

Because dict hashes its keys then store them in a set-like data structure. As a result the newly created {key :value} overrides the older one and in your case the duplicates. I think this may be a duplicate question

Comment: it is not a set-like data structure. There can be multiple `None` which needs to be filled by keys. ex: `['a', None, None, 'b', None]`

Comment: Sorry i can't understand you. what is the source of this list?